# how to close modal popup when browser back button is clicked in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

We make use of modal component from https://github.com/yuche/vue-strap. When browser back button is clicked, the default behavior is back to previous path but the modal popup isn't closed. How can I change the behavior to close the modal popup upon browser's back button click event?

Comment: What is Vue's official modal component?

Comment: I dont think they have one, he's most likely using something from Awesome-Vue's github. Anyways, this is a routing issue. If your modal appears at one route, then when the route changes, it should go away. We need you code.

Comment: Sorry guys, double checked that it's modal component from https://github.com/yuche/vue-strap.

Comment: In the component that opens the modal, add a `beforeRouteLeave` navigation guard to close the modal

Answer (score 2):

This helped me.

https://jessarcher.com/blog/closing-modals-with-the-back-button-in-a-vue-spa/

```js
created() {
  const backButtonRouteGuard = this.$router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

    if (from.name == 'menu') {
      /* Blocking back button in menu route */
      next(false);
      
      this.yourCallBackMethod()
    } else {
      /* allowing all other routes*/
      next(true);
    }
  });

  this.$once('hook:destroyed', () => {
    backButtonRouteGuard();
  });
},

methods: {
    yourCallBackMethod() {
      // Go to the previous step, or close the modal
    }
},
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```